# Why the array seem to be longer than its maximum length?

Tags: java, arrays

Im new, I try to write some code, its for counting the string letter, space, and such. So, i set array length 50. But when i run the code later and enter more than 50 characters, it still can be run,and the total count can be more than 50, why? thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class javaexcrises {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String astrg = new String();
        char[] ch = new char[50];
        int charcount=0;
        int spaccount=0;
        int numcount=0;
        int othcount=0;

        System.out.println("Please enter some word ");
            if(scan.hasNextLine()){
                astrg = scan.nextLine();
                ch = astrg.toCharArray();

                int i;
                for(i=0;i<astrg.length();i++){
                    if(Character.isLetter(ch[i])){
                        charcount++;
                    }
                    else if(Character.isDigit(ch[i])){
                        numcount++;
                    }
                    else if(Character.isSpaceChar(ch[i])){
                        spaccount++;
                    }
                    else{
                        othcount++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Character = "+charcount);
                System.out.println("Space = "+spaccount);
                System.out.println("Number = "+numcount);
                System.out.println("Others ="+othcount);
                System.out.println("Total = "+ch.length);
            }
            scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can omit ’=new char[50]’ and nothing will change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 ch = astrg.toCharArray();
```

`toCharArray()` returns a reference to a NEW array, and that reference replaces the old one that you allocated.  That new array is large enough to contain the entire input string.

Comment: Also worth noting similar happens with `String astrg = new String();` and `astrg = scan.nextLine();`: the first assignment is redundant (as is using `new String()`, vs `""`).

Comment: @tommy123456789 this is something you should be able to see using a debugger. The more you practice using one, the faster you will solve this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1):

When we do astrg.toCharArray(), It returns a newly allocated character array, whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.

If you remove new char[50] also it will not affect.